# How to format TEdit with car plate (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I would like to know how to only allow one Format in `TEdit` (XXX-0000) ...

I searched all day on the Internet and only found very old tutorials for Delphi where `EditMask` existed, but now (at least in Delphi Tokyo) there is no more `EditMask`.

I tried to write code to format the `TEdit`, but it did not work.

Can anybody help me?

I'm developing for Android (using Delphi Tokyo).

Comment: Seems you are looking for TMaskEdit instead of TEdit.

Comment: Worth noting that this is for Brazillian car plates, which follow this format.  Car plate formats will naturally be different for other countries.

Comment: In any case, it's generally best to let people type whatever they want - show the format you want and validate to indicate whether what they've written is valid, but don't bother trying to suppress characters that shouldn't be there.  If they type something invalid and you simply suppress the character people sometimes just think the key is broken, etc, because you've given them no feedback that they've done something wrong.

Comment: What J suggests also allows you to handle multiple formats if needed, or better handle the possibility of the format ever changing in the future.

Comment: Why not format the input in the OnChange event?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout:  Because of what J... has said.

Comment: @MartynA I know and I fully agree. but this is just an idea in case OP really wanted todo this.

Comment: Looks like the poster is developing for Android which means Firemonkey where there is no TMaskEdit like there is for VCL. Added the Firemonkey tag to the question.

Comment: And what if a country has vanity plates? For example, in Back to the Future, doc's Delorean had the plate `OUTATIME`. I also know someone with the plate `LITIG8`.

Comment: I'm not worrying about the issue of cars from other countries ... I'm developing an application for a small company that will only need the cars in Brazil, but is afraid to fill our license plates in a non-standard way, so I need to format the TEdit =\

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout 
I tried but could not do something good

Comment: For myself, I understand that it would be better to let employees fill in anyway, but I have to format it

Comment: @user3602803 Well, be careful about your assumptions.  Starting last year, even, Brazil has been moving to switch all car plates to the [Mercosur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_Mercosur) standard format (by 2023) which introduces plates with **LLL NLNN** formats.  Seven of the largest cities in Brazil are already issuing plates with this format.  Also, diplomatic plates will not follow the standard format either.

Comment: J, The application will only be used for 2 months, it is a company work.